# Enabled Heroku Automated Cert Management but still No Green Bar

Tags: security, ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I have a Heroku app with a paid Hobby Plan. I'm struggling to secure the connection for the site despite following instructions...

I enabled ACM like so:

```
heroku certs:auto
```

Then checked the status like so:

```
heroku certs:auto

Domain               Status
───────────────────  ──────
www.sitename.com      OK
```

I checked the DNS like so:

```
heroku domains

=== sitename Heroku Domain
appname.herokuapp.com

=== sitename Custom Domains
Domain Name          DNS Record Type  DNS Target
───────────────────  ───────────────  ─────────────────────────────────
www.sitename.com  CNAME            www.sitename.com.herokudns.com
```

Everything looks okay but I still dont have a green Secure connection.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: The site was not showing up as secured because of incorrect DNS being used.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I hired a freelancer and he fixed it.

He updated the dns on my domain and now its secured.

I thought the dns were fine but apparently not.

Comment: Neato - but can you provide any more information about what he did to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate is fine on the domain in your question, connections are made over https, nice and secure (see the lock icon).

Thr url bar is not green, because your certificate is not an EV (extended validation) one. You need an EV certificate for the green bar.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to go to your DNS provider site to setup CNAME for www to point to "DNS target".  Useful information.

https://www.hypersoftllc.com/blog/setting-up-ssl-tls-using-automated-certificate-management-acm-from-heroku-using-a-godaddy-registered-domain/

Lastly, you can use the dig utility.  If your CNAME is still pointing to .herokuapp.com, then your setup is incomplete.  You should see the CNAME points to the "DNS Target" given by heroku certs:auto command.

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/heroku-error-ssl/